# multiplication of polynomials using structs and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I've been trying for a while to implement the long multiplication for polynomials and I still haven't figured out how to do it. I keep getting garbage numbers.

here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Poly
{
    int degree;
    int *coeffs; // array of coefficients from lowest degree to highest degree
};

Poly* readPoly();
void outputPoly(const Poly* p, char x);
Poly* multPoly(const Poly* a, const Poly* b);

int main()
{

    cout << "First polynomial" << endl;
    Poly* a = readPoly();
    cout << "Second polynomial" << endl;
    Poly* b = readPoly();


    cout << "a = ";
    outputPoly(a, 'x');
    cout << "b = ";
    outputPoly(b, 'x');

    Poly* prodOfPoly = multPoly(a,b);
    cout << "d = ";
    outputPoly(prodOfPoly, 'x');

    return 0;
}

Poly* readPoly()
{
    int deg;
    int* A;
    cout << "Input the degree: ";
    cin >> deg;
    A = new int[deg+1]; //add 1 for constants

    cout << "Input coefficients: ";

    //assign coefficients
    for (int i = 0; i <= deg; i++){
        cin >> A[i];
    }

    cout << endl;

    //create the polynomial structure and assign values to the fields
    Poly* p;
    p = new Poly;
    p->degree = deg;
    p->coeffs = A;

    return p;
}
void outputPoly(const Poly* p, char x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= p->degree; i++){
        //coefficient is non-zero
        if ( p->coeffs[i] != 0){
            //exponent is 0
            if (i == 0) 
                cout << *(p->coeffs);
            //exponent is 1 and coefficient is 1
            else if ( i == 1 && p->coeffs[i] == 1) 
                cout << " + " <<  x;
            //exponent is 1 and coefficient is NOT 1
            else if ( i == 1 && p->coeffs[i] != 1) 
                cout << " + " << p->coeffs[i] << "*" << x;
            //exponent is > 1 and coefficient is 1
            else if ( p->coeffs[i] == 1) 
                cout << " + " << x << "^" << i;
            //coefficient is positive
            else if ( p->coeffs[i] > 0) 
                cout  << " + " << p->coeffs[i] << "*" << x << "^" << i;
            //coefficient is negative
            else if ( p->coeffs[i] < 0)
                cout  << " - " << -p->coeffs[i] << "*" <<  x << "^" << i;
        }
        //polynomial is a constant
        else if( p->coeffs[i] == 0 && p->degree == 0)
            cout << p->coeffs[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
Poly* multPoly(const Poly* a, const Poly* b)
{
    Poly* finalProduct;
    finalProduct = new Poly;
    finalProduct->degree = a->degree + b->degree; 

    int* productCoeffs = new int[finalProduct->degree - 1];

    //solve for product of polynomials
    for (int i = 0; i != finalProduct->degree; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j != finalProduct->degree; j++)
            productCoeffs[i + j] += a->coeffs[i] * b->coeffs[j];
    }

    finalProduct->coeffs = productCoeffs;

    return finalProduct;
}
```

I know that I get the garbage numbers because at the line:

```
for (int i = 0; i != finalProduct->degree; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j != finalProduct->degree; j++)
                productCoeffs[i + j] += a->coeffs[i] * b->coeffs[j];
```

If the input I have is

```
a: degree 3, coeffs, 0 1 2 3
b: degree 2, coeffs, 1 2 -3
```

degree of the product would then be 7-1 (a: 3+1 & b: 2+1) = 6
then `a->coeffs[i]` will have garbage numbers because `a->coeffs` will only have 3+1  maximum monomials.

The output should be: `d = 4x^2 + 4x^3 - 9x^5,`
but I get: `d = 9398672 + x + 9371988*x^2 + 4*x^3 - 1112350759*x^4 - 2063433372*x^5`
If anyone could help and lead me to fixing the code that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what your code is doing to be honest, but it's pretty clear you're overflowing a buffer in your `multPoly` function:

```
int* productCoeffs = new int[finalProduct->degree - 1];

//solve for product of polynomials
for (int i = 0; i != finalProduct->degree; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j != finalProduct->degree; j++)
        productCoeffs[i + j] += a->coeffs[i] * b->coeffs[j];
}
```

`i + j` can easily be >= `finalProduct->degree - 1`, meaning you are writing past the end of the `productCoeffs` array.

If you change the array allocation to

```
int* productCoeffs = new int[finalProduct->degree * 2];
```

it seems to fix the garbage numbers in the output. Whether that gives you the right answer or not, I have no idea :)

Comment: but that would mean there should be 14 monomials in the array right? did you try running the code?

Comment: @BoytanodPitongulo I made it clear I couldn't follow what the code was doing and was just pointing out the buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Following up the answer by @JonathanPotter...

Memory allocation for the new object should be:

```
int* productCoeffs = new int[finalProduct->degree + 1];
                                               //^^^ +, not -.
```

The loops should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i != a->degree; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j != b->degree; j++)
        productCoeffs[i + j] += a->coeffs[i] * b->coeffs[j];
}
```

Before the above loop, I would add code to initialize the coefficients of the product to be 0.

```
for (int i = 0; i != finalProduct->degree; i++){
    productCoeffs[i] = 0.0;
}
```

**Update**

A correct implementation of `multPoly`:

```
Poly* multPoly(const Poly* a, const Poly* b)
{
   Poly* finalProduct;
   finalProduct = new Poly;
   finalProduct->degree = a->degree + b->degree; 

   int* productCoeffs = new int[finalProduct->degree + 1];

   for (int i = 0; i <= finalProduct->degree; i++){
      productCoeffs[i] = 0.0;
   }

   //solve for product of polynomials
   for (int i = 0; i <= a->degree; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j <= b->degree; j++)
         productCoeffs[i + j] += a->coeffs[i] * b->coeffs[j];
   }

   finalProduct->coeffs = productCoeffs;

   return finalProduct;
}
```

See it woking at http://ideone.com/S7Tc2R.

Comment: I don't get why the array allocation should be int[finalProduct->degree * 2]. That would be too much right?

Comment: No, I don't think you need that much memory. See my updated answer.

Comment: I followed your code and everything but I still keep getting garbage numbers and not getting the right output. Are you running the program?